# svn - how to handle directories which get overriden

Tags: svn, commit, addition, overwrite

I was just wondering if there's a workaround for adding files/directories to your svn directories which get overwritten completely without ruining the svn structure and having to export or start from new again.

You must be thinking, if they are overwrritten completely, why do they need to be in svn in the first place? Let's just say I want everything to be safe.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Andreas

Comment: Please, don't use "Hi" and "Thanks Somebody" in your posts, as signature is already in the bottom. Thanks.

Comment: What? Do you mean the `.svn` folders specific to the SVN system? Or _your_ working copy folder? This question is unclear, IMO. Please elaborate.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment, ok so let's say you a build directory added to your svn. and then you execute an ant script and that build directory is completely removed and re-created. Then you have a problem with svn when you try to commit/update saying svn build is not a working directory. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Of course you have an issue then: 'you've just painted over _my_ masterpiece!' That's not _my_ [SVN's] fault. It seems you have a compatibility issue here; yet you want to put more pressure on the already wounded dog that is SVN - look to `ant` for the solution as SVN depends on that structure and ant is the trespasser.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem with a tool we're using for some artwork (ArtText 2).  We want to commit the ArtText documents in svn, just like we do all our other work documents... but these things happen to be saved as bundles (folders), and it blows away the .svn every time you resave them.  Major PITA, and it's a shame there isn't some "svn fix" command that just tells svn to re-download the missing svn directory and get on with its life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: files and directories created or recreated by the build process **don't belong into the repository**.

If you choose to ignore this best practice (for what reason ever), I would suggest that you  write a shell script or a small tool which deletes every file recursively in a directory tree, but keeps the folder structure intact and omits the `.svn` folders. Call this tool in your build process whereever you now are deleting complete folders.

Addendum: here is a former SO post, dealing with the topic of versioning generated code, which IMHO is almost the same problem:

[Subversion - dealing with code generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874307/subversion-dealing-with-code-generation)

Comment: An exception to this rule could be the end product, such as the `release` build output, i.e. that last deployable setup file.

Comment: @Mr Disappointment: maybe. But I would not recommend using SVN for versioning of the release packages. In our case, those packages contain large binary files. We prefer using a folder structure on a file server for that, having date & version number as part of the folder name. Those folders can be accessed from non-developers, without having access to SVN and the source code repository.

Comment: Agreed, t'was just an aside - and the exception, not the rule. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think we are doing what you are asking.

We have projects with the following layout:

```
.\Project
.\project\Component
.\Project\Bin         -- svn:ignored
.\Project\Bin\Debug   -- svn:ignored (recursively from parent)
.\Project\Bin\Release -- svn:ignored (recursively from parent)
```

The build directories are svn:ignore'd and we only commit the sources required to rebuild the binaries. Our build tool auto-creates the missing output directories during the build.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by "overwritten completely"? Are the directories actually deleted? Or are just their contents overwritten?

We've been using a similar approach successfully for years; every night, a job dumps the metadata scripts from our development databases, adds all new files and does a svn commit.

But this requires that the directory structure remains intact (esp. the .svn subdirectories).

Kind regards, Frank

Comment: they get deleted and recreated.